# 401 Unauthorized with rails 4.1.4 and devise 3.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mongoid

using rails 4.1.4, devise 3.2.4 and mongoid 4.0,

I have this issue when I login; I am redirecting the user after login to stores/dashboard;
for some reason I got the 401 Unauthorized. Also I had to include the patch for the user model.
Due a reason authenticate_user is not working properly

Controller

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]

  def index
  end

  def dashboard
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'stores/dashboard' => 'stores#dashboard', :as => 'user_root'
root :to => 'stores#index' , :as => 'stores'
```

patch on user.rb

```
class << self
    def serialize_from_session(key,salt)
      #record = to_adapter.get(key[0].to_param)                                                                                                                                 
      record = to_adapter.get(key.to_s)
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
end
```

logs

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 09:48:59 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n7t7mLISBOGMYWxJWzw8qNHwP3y9HGR+79P0vmEodEg=", "user"=>{"email"=>"victornsosa@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 0.7452ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=prometheus_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"email"=>"victornsosa@gmail.com"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.6844ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=prometheus_development collection=users selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53f5eded6265743c0a010000')} update={"$set"=>{"last_sign_in_at"=>2014-08-21 13:32:55 UTC, "current_sign_in_at"=>2014-08-21 13:48:59 UTC, "sign_in_count"=>9}} flags=[]
                         COMMAND      database=prometheus_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 0.5836ms
Redirected to /stores/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 88ms


Started GET "/stores/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 09:48:59 -0400
Processing by StoresController#dashboard as HTML
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=prometheus_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"[{\"$oid\"=>\"53f5eded6265743c0a010000\"}]"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.3786ms
**Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms**


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 09:48:59 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 18.9ms)
```

Also I found out that: if **user_signed_in?** is not working properly neither. I am guessing the issue is releated to the use of mongoid.

The signup is working including sending the email; the login seen to be working and redirecting to the correct page as the log said; but there is a issue with the filter because is not letting the user in.

Comment: Why the patch on user?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the serialization of the object user with mongoid, check this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2949; and it fix one issue I used to have.

Comment: There is a bug in the api. thats why I try using the patach on user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out the line below from the cookies_serializer.rb

Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json

Delete cookies.
Restart server.

found it:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2949